# There was a problem parsing the package giving error when I downloaded apk file

Tags: android, apk

There was a problem parsing the package giving error when I downloaded apk file

```
Uri uri= Uri.parse(downloadUrl);
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setTitle(title);
        request.setDescription(description);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
```

Comment: I'm sure the apk file is not corrupt. I want to download apk file from url when i click a button.

Comment: If DownloadManager downloads a file and saves to storage it will not parse the file. So the code you posted wil not produce a parsing package error. Better post the code you used.

Comment: request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,apkName);
        //request.setMimeType("*/*");
        request.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);                                                                  this is the rest of the code.